# Summary, tensorflow, which data to feed when evaluating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

In the [Hands-on TensorBoard video by Dandelion Mané](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=627s) he writes the following code when talking about collecting some summaries and writing them to disk:

```
#(... some code and some summaries...)
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/mnist_demo/3")
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

for i in range(2001):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  if i % 5 == 0:
    s = sess.run(merged_summary, feed_dict={x:batch[0], y: batch[1]})
    writer.add_summary(s, i)
```

So I took inspiration from there for my code, below I show a snippet:

```
costs = []   # To keep track of the cost per epoch
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Z5, labels=Y))
tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        minibatches_cost = 0
        seed = seed + 1
        minibatches_train = random_mini_batches(X_train, Y_train, minibatch_size, seed)
        num_minibatches_train = len(minibatches_train)

        for minibatch in minibatches_train:

            # Select a minibatch
            (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch

            # Run the session to execute the optimizer and the cost, the feedict should contain a minibatch for (X,Y).
            _ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y})

            minibatches_cost += minibatch_cost    # Adding the cost per minibatch

        epoch_cost = minibatches_cost / num_minibatches_train  # Cost per epoch

        if print_cost == True and epoch % 5 == 0:      # Print the cost
            print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))
            print ("Time elapsed: %i" % t_elapsed)

        if epoch % 1 == 0:                             # Append the cost
            costs.append(epoch_cost)

        if epoch % 1 == 0:                             # Write summaries
            summary_str = merged_summary.eval(feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y})
            file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch)
```

**My question is whether I am feeding the correct data to the session when evaluating merged_summary**, because the way I am doing it now, the cost that is going to be written to disk in the summary is the cost of one minibatch (actually the last minibatch, generated with random_mini_batches), whereas the cost per epoch (epoch_cost in the code) that I save in the costs variable to then plot it and study its evolution, is the average cost per epoch (a more accurate measure of the cost than the cost per minibatch, I assume).

I guess feeding the whole training data is not the solution, but I am a bit confused with why only feeding one batch of the training data when evaluating the summaries.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow if you want the cost averaged over the entire dataset you need to use a metric, not a summary. Look at the documentation for tf metrics for more information on how to use them.

Comment: Could you expand the answer a bit more?
Now I am using a tf.Summary.Value to record the data I compute in epoch_cost, for every epoch. However my question is if it makes sense to evaluate a summary with only one minibatch? Is it okey to use it as a tool for approximately predicting the trend?

Comment: Ah, whether it will work to predict the trend depends a lot on the variance of the thing you're looking at in your dataset. Note that tensorboard lets you add smoothing to your summary plots which will help a lot.